# How to flip the texture on a CC3PlaneNode?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I'm creating a CC3PlaneNode (cocos3d) with code that looks something like this:

```
CC3PlaneNode *bnode = [CC3PlaneNode nodeWithName: name];
CC3Texture *texture = [CC3Texture textureFromFile: texName];
[bnode populateAsCenteredRectangleWithSize: sz
                           andTessellation: ccg(1, 1)
                               withTexture: texture
                             invertTexture: YES];
bnode.material.specularColor = kCCC4FLightGray;
bnode.material.emissionColor = kCCC4FWhite;
bnode.material.isOpaque = NO;
bnode.shouldCullBackFaces = NO;
bnode.isTouchEnabled = YES;
bnode.location = loc;
[bnode retainVertexLocations];
```

Under certain circumstances, I'd like the plane to display the mirror image of its texture (*a la* the Flip Horizontal feature on many image programs.)  I don't just want to flip the plane, itself, because that would throw out-of-position all of it's child-nodes, which is undesirable behaviour.

That is, if X & Y are parts of my texture, and "c" and "c'" are child-nodes in this diagram:

```
+--------+
|        |
|  x   y |
|        |
+--------+
 c      c'
```

after the flip, I want things to look like this:

```
+--------+
|        |
|  y   x |
|        |
+--------+
 c      c'
```

Other than not wanting to rotate/spin/flip the plane, itself, I'm otherwise pretty flexible on a solution.

Any hints?

Thanks!